# unable to count the result with a condition using codeigniter query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am trying to count rows of bookdetails  table where display_id is as argument. Say i passed `$id='3'`. But i am not getting the output.
I think the code which i am trying is wrong. Please help me to write this query correctly

```
  //--- Counting the rows of bookdetails of table where display_id is as argument------------------------------------------------------------- 
 public function record_count_for_secondtopBooks($id) {
     $this->load->database(); 
    return $this->db->count_all("bookdetails",array('display_id'=>$id)); 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$this->db->where('display_id',$id);
$result = $this->db->count_all("bookdetails");
```

or Chain em'

```
$result = $this->db->where('display_id',$id)->count_all("bookdetails");
```

**check:**

```
echo'<pre>';
print_r($result);
echo'</pre>';
```

Answer (score 4):

count_all returns the number of rows in a particular

```
echo $this->db->count_all('my_table');
```

Try this

```
$this->db->where('display_id', $id);
$this->db->from('bookdetails"');
$this->db->count_all_results();
```

Answer (score 1):

count_all accepts only one argument and that is table name. So you will get count of all records in that table. as written in manual:

> Permits you to determine the number of rows in a particular table.
>   Submit the table name in the first parameter. Example:

Answer (score 0):

Just try this,

```
$this->db->where('display_id', $id);
$query = $this->db->count_all('bookdetails');

return $query;
```

Comment: Did you check your $id has value? Do you have records for that value?

Comment: i want to return the count value. i am doing this for pagination

Answer (score 0):

please try below code

```
 public function record_count_for_secondtopBooks($id) {

$this->db->where('display_id',$id);
$q = $this->db->get('bookdetails');
return $q->num_rows();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public function record_count_with_where($table_name,$column_name,$type)
  {
    $this->db->select($column_name);
    $this->db->where($column_name,$type);
    $q=$this->db->get($table_name);
    $count=$q->result();
    return count($count);

  }
```